# SAPI 5.4/11 Japanese TTS in Delphi GUI vs console

Tags: delphi, com, text-to-speech, sapi

Trying to use MS Speech API v11 with a Japanese engine (MS Haruka) in Delphi 10.3.

I have a sample app with a form and a button. The click handler goes:

```pascal
uses SpeechLib11_TLB; // Imported from "Microsoft Speech Object Library" v.B.0
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    v: ISpeechVoice;
begin
    v := CoSpVoice.Create();
    //5.4 only but won't hurt
    v.Voice := v.GetVoices('language=411', '').Item(0);

    v.Speak('時間', SVSFDefault);
end;
```

That causes an error, "Catastrophic failure" (HRESULT 0x8000FFFF, E_UNEXPECTED). The code that I think should be equivalent works in a C++ project:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#import "libid:d3c4a7f2-7d27-4332-b41f-593d71e16db1" rename_namespace("SAPI") //v11
//#import "libid:C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628" rename_namespace("SAPI") //v5.4

int wmain()
{
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    {
        SAPI::ISpeechVoicePtr v;
        v.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SAPI::SpVoice));

        //Needed for 5.4 only, but won't hurt
        SAPI::ISpeechObjectTokensPtr voices(v->GetVoices(L"language=411", L""));
        v->Voice = voices->Item(0);

        v->Speak(L"時間", SAPI::SVSFDefault);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

That works and speaks. So the SAPI *per se* is not broken on the machine. The platform is Win32 in both projects, not Win64. The Japanese voice is the default one (no need to set it explicitly).

Same result with SAPI 5.4 proper (not OneCore), although the Japanese voice is not the default one and I had to add a couple of lines to set it as the default.

---

Further debugging reveals that on the Delphi side, as much as calling the `v.Voice` property getter immediately after the first line causes the same error, E_UNEXPECTED. Meanwhile, the `Voice` *setter* works if you pass it a valid voice token object from `GetVoices()`. It looks as if the voice object initializes itself to its defaults correctly in C++, but somehow skips that in the Delphi project.

Requesting `v.Voice` right after construction works though in Delphi with SAPI 5.4. Calling `Speak()` still throws a E_UNEXPECTED.

**What could be the difference in process/threadwide execution context between C++ and Delphi?** It's not the thread locale. The COM thread model is apartment in both.

The same Delphi code works with an English phrase and an English voice (MS Helen). So whatever init failure there might be, it's probably specific to Haruka.

The SAPI 11 runtime is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225). The language data for TTS are [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224).

---

Another data point. I've rewritten the SAPI logic in Delphi to use SAPI 5.4 OneCore instead (not SAPI 5.4 proper). Unlike 5.4 and 11, it doesn't expose an IDispatch-based interface, and it's somewhat clumsier specifically in Delphi, but Japanese TTS works. The question, *as initially posed*, is still unanswered, but at least there's a workaround. I'll write up an answer, but I won't accept it.

---

However, it's not the custom vs. dual distinction that's to blame. I've changed the logic to use custom interfaces instead of automation ones **with SAPI 5.4 proper** (the typelib defines both), still got `E_UNEXPECTED` from `Speak()`. There's no error info.

---

Here's another beautiful data point: SAPI 5.4 TTS with automation based API works and talks as expected **in a Delphi console app**. So it's not even Delphi specific, it's somehow VCL specific. What is it with Delphi GUI? Needless to say, I immediately retested the C++ snippet in a C++ GUI application, with a form and a button. The C++ one talks.

Comment: Try casting to `WideString('時間')` or `PWideChar(WideString('時間'))`

Comment: Just read the part about `v.Voice` property getter also raising but then you say "The same Delphi code works with an English phrase and an English voice". Do you set [`CoInitFlags`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Win.ComObj.CoInitFlags) to `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`?

Comment: I don't set CoInitFlags explicitly, but I called CoInitializeEx with 2
 (COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) and got S_FALSE - already initialized with the same model.

Comment: Re: WideString: same error. Strings are wide by default in Delphi 10.3.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Delphi strings are *Unicode* by default in D2009+, but they are not *wide*. `WideString` and `UnicodeString` are completely different types with different memory management semantics. COM uses `WideString`, not `UnicodeString`

Comment: The first argument of `Speak` is `PWideChar`. Were there no silent conversion from `string` to `WideString` to `PWideChar`, Delphi would surely emit a type mismatch error. Anyway, I've placed `WideString()` around the literal and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a workaround.

Windows 10 comes with two flavors of 32-bit SAPI. There's SAPI 5.4 proper (in `system32\speech`), and also SAPI 5.4 OneCore (in `system32\speech_onecore`). The latter, even though it's superficially the same, exposes a different typelib - there's no automation support, all interfaces are custom instead of dual. What's more important, when you download the Japanese TTS voice in the Windows 10 Settings app, you end up with 3 voices under OneCore ([Sayaka, somehow, missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618283/where-is-sayaka)) and only one, Haruka, under 5.4 proper.

Delphi can consume custom interfaces in a typelib, but the methods look somewhat clumsier. Also, the enumeration of voices in the automation API is cleaner. Anyway, here goes.

```
uses SpeechLib54Core_TLB; // This time it's OneCore
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    v: ISpVoice;
    cat: ISpObjectTokenCategory;
    toks: IEnumSpObjectTokens;
    tok: ISpObjectToken;
    sno: LongWord;
    hr: HResult;
    n: Cardinal;
begin
    v := CoSpVoice.Create();
    hr := v.GetVoice(tok);
    tok.GetCategory(cat);
    cat.EnumTokens('language=411', '', toks); //411 means Japanese
    toks.GetCount(n);
    if n = 0 then
        exit; // No Japanese voices installed
    toks.Item(0, tok); //Take the first one - typically Ayumi
    v.SetVoice(tok);

    v.Speak('時間', 0, sno);
end;
```

Note that passing a Japanese string literal to a COM method works without an explicit cast to a wide string.